# Magento 1.5 - Sales > Order > edit order and shipping methods disappear

Tags: admin, shipping-methods, sales-order, edit

When i am editing order in Magento 1.5 and change price then click on “Update Item and Qty’s” button the shipping method disappear. Instead of shipping methods there is a link “Get shipping methods and rates”, but when I click it nothing's happend - page reloads and still there are no methods. what is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you check your server php error log?

Comment: yes i was check in error log file. there was error "Cannot retrieve payment method instance".